# How to disable a form in vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I think this is the most obvious ability:

How to disable `v-form` in vuetify? with all their inputs and buttons inside `v-form` or `v-card`

I was check in [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms) but I can't see any references.

Answer (score 7):

**Update 1:**
Since version [**2.3.0**](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/tag/v2.3.0) `v-form` has `disabled` property, it sets to `true` it disables all children inputs.

```
<template>
 <v-form :disabled="isDisabled">
  <v-input ... />
 </v-form>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
  data: () => ({
   isDisabled: false
  });
 }
</script>
```

---

They haven't implemented such a thing to disable all children of a `v-form` yet. You should bind `disabled` prop to `false` for every control.

```
:disabled="true"
```

e.g:

```
<v-text-field
  v-model="firstname"
  :disabled="true"
  :rules="nameRules"
  :counter="10"
  label="First name"
  required
></v-text-field>
```

A link to this feature-request on Github:

[[Feature Request] disable prop for v-form that disables all child input elements](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/1707)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the JS props to disable your form, using the following code on your

> mounted

.
On your mounted:

```
$('#yourFormName :input').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: I am NOT the person who downvoted you (wanted to clear this out). But bear in mind that your solution, while valid is using jQuery and the question is about Vue.js (Vuetify is a Vue design framework). You can use both but it kind of defeat the point of Vue. Don't let this discourage you from posting solutions on SO though. Some people use jQuery and might land on this page. They will be happy to find your solution that fits THEIR problem.